# How to automatically scroll to the bottom in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

In my AngularJS app there is a controller which contains a list with messages:

```
$scope.messages = []
```

This list is updated as the application runs. In the template it is rendered in the following way:

```
<div style="height: 200px; overflow: auto">
...
    <li ng-repeat="msg in messages">{{msg}}</li>
...
```

But when more messages comes than fits the 200px height, the scroll remains on the top.

How to automatically scroll to the bottom of the message list?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a directive "scroll-glue" from this library https://github.com/Luegg/angularjs-scroll-glue that solves the problem.

Just add scroll-glue directive to the div:

```
<div style="height: 200px; overflow: auto" scroll-glue>
...
```